# Find Max numeric value of two varchar fields

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I'm trying to find the max value contained in two separate fields of my table.

The code I'm using in my model is:

```
$query = $this->db->query("select max($field1) as max_id_1 from default_table1");
$row1 = $query->row_array();
$query = $this->db->query("select max($field2) as max_id_2 from default_table1");
$row2 = $query->row_array();
return max($row1['max_id_1'], $row2['max_id_2']);
```

I'm a complete novice where PHP and CodeIgniter is concerned - as I'm sure my code demonstrates :)

It is working insofar as it's returning values, but not the maximum values I have in the fields. For instance I know there is a 4000 value but the highest returned is 750.

I'm wondering if this is because the fields are of type VARCHAR because although they predominantly contain numbers there are some that contain characters (- or &) or the word 'to' so I couldn't use the INT type.
Because of using VARCHAR is it failing to see that 4000 is larger than 750?

If so is there a way to cast the field contents as integer before checking for the max value, and will this be affected by the non-integer values in the fields?

All offers of help and advice is gratefully received.

Tony.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using SQL using MySQL's implicit type conversion:

```
select max(case when (field1+0)>(field2+0) then field1+0 else field2+0 end)
from default_table1
```

Using +0 would convert varchar to number and also ignore any characters that follow after the number. If you still need the original content, you can write the query like this:

```
select case when (field1+0)>(field2+0) then field1 else field2 end
from default_table1
order by case when (field1+0)>(field2+0) then field1+0 else field2+0 end desc
limit 1
```

Comment: Thanks for that @milan. It's working - certainly better than the code I came up with - but it doesn't seem to pick up the maximum value if the comparison is between a number and a null value (for instance $field1 = 4000, $field2 = NULL). Would this be expected? Any ideas how to overcome this? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Sure, use COALESCE. Instead of field1 and field2 use COALESCE(field1,0) and COALESCE(field2,0)

Comment: Superb @milan. That's worked brilliantly :) Thanks a lot for your help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, oops, I've forgot the mysql part
You should do the same thing, cast to integer:

```
select max(cast($field1 to unsigned)) as max_id_1 from default_table1
```

---

It depends of your data, but you may try something like that

```
return max((int)$row1['max_id_1'], (int)$row2['max_id_2']);
```

Have a look to the PHP doc on [string to int conversion](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion)

Comment: This won't work, because he is doing a max() during the query on VARCHAR columns.  The values he is getting for `$row1['max_id_1']` AND `$row2['max_id_2']` are probably invalid.  You are, at best, providing the maximum of two numbers, which are not the maximum numbers in the db anyway, and therefore does not solve the problem

Comment: Yes, I've seen it like 30s before your comment :) Thank you anyway

Answer (score -1):

What you are really asking for is a way for codeigniter to convert the strings to numbers, and the find the max values of those.  I don't know of any way to do this in codeigniter.

If you really want this, you have two options:

1. loop through all the rows in the table, and use php to parse out the number, while looking for the maximum number
2. Add a number column to the db, and do the string-to-number parsing in this new column whenever the values are inserted.

The first option is *incredibly* inefficient, and the second is probably your best bet.